# I have multiple images in the product. I want to show only one image with details and price on Shopify section. What should I do?

Tags: schema, shopify, product

I have multiple products and each product has multiple images. I want to show only one image with a description and price on Shopify Section page.
Here is my code.

```html
{% for block in section.blocks %}
   {% assign product = all_products[block.settings.product] %}
     {% for image in product.images %} 
       <img src="{{ image.src | product_img_url: 'master' }}" >
     {{ product.price | money_without_trailing_zeros }} 
     {{product.description}}
     {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% schema %}
{
   "name": "Demo",
   "blocks": [
      {
         "type": "new-arrival",
         "name": "New Arrival",
         "settings": [
            {
               "type": "product",
               "id": "product",
               "label": "Product"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
{% endschema %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{% for block in section.blocks %}
  {% assign product = all_products[block.settings.product] %}
     {% if product.featured_image %}
       <img src="{{ product.featured_image.src | product_img_url: 'master' }}" >
     {% else %}
       <img src="{{ product.images[0].src | product_img_url: 'master' }}" >
     {% endif %}
     {{ product.price | money_without_trailing_zeros }} 
     {{product.description}}
     {% endfor %}
 {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Removing inside for loop and add if condition with featured_image, is a good idea. Thank you again, Onkar.